# Как проверить исправность hdmi разъема?

Tags: экран, монитор, hdmi

Как **проверить** исправность порта `hdmi` ? Нужно тест какой то провести ? Почему порт отвечает через раз. ...вообще вдруг перестал отвечать и сравнительно мало использовался.

и если порт все-таки испортился, **что нужно** покупать, как переходник ? В интернете пишут, что включает оба монитора, а по факту продают [свич](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Yof.jpg), какие параметры надо смотреть, есть ли вообще двойник для hdmi ?

очень [нужно](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUTJr.jpg) подключить второй экран

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переходники c DP на HDMI; DVI(цифровой) на HDMI; Последний стоит около 250 рублей, и проверишь роботоспособность видяхи. Посмотри порты моника, может  них проблема. Кабель точно целый?

Comment: да, кабель целый и даже три. Меняю, второй порт отвечает и все транслирует, а первый молчит. ВидеоКарта `NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650` -как ее работоспособность проверяют ? //DP - HDMI cabel  смотрю в инете, такого ведь выхода не вижу на компе (DP) ? //а DVI они все стандартные ? потому что дома есть DVI-DVI так они побольше и поменьше, а как узнать какой нужен ?

Comment: DVI-HDMI как правильно подобрать ?

Comment: [такой подойдет ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgJS9.png), по-моему не подойдет, потому что на компе,  [поменьше выглядит](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIsgu.jpg)

Comment: а еще, у меня вот [такой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6UcM.jpg) есть на компе, это что за кабель ?

Comment: Который поменьше это VGA, - аналоговый сигнал. Конвертеры с него на HDMI около 500, но там качество теряется. Последний подойдёт - это DVI-D он передаёт цифру. Чтобы пользоваться им тебе подойдёт кабель DVI-D (Если у тебя есть кабель  DVI-D to DVI-D и оба папы то втыкай его в моник(там скореее всего есть этот порт)). Про который первый ты говорил, он подойдёт.

Comment: не могу найти в инете DVI-D -hdmi

Comment: https://www.ozon.ru/product/adapter-perehodnik-gsmin-rt-91-dvi-i-24-5-m-hdmi-f-chernyy-250448972/ на первый попавшийся на озоне.

Comment: попробую разобраться, выручил так выручил

Comment: `HDMI HDTV to DVI`, а то что тут нету D, а просто DVI, не DVI-D, это какую роль играет ?

Comment: да играет  вот этот точно подойдёт https://www.ozon.ru/product/dvi-hdmi-adapter-belsis-dvunapravlennyy-konverter-dvi-male-to-hdmi-female-podderzhka-1080p-265816986/

Comment: но этот дешман лучше поищи прям папа DVI-D на HDMI (не в коем случае не HDTV) В DVI-D  там зубчиков лишних нет в отличии от DVI-I DVI-A  набери в инете

Comment: папа это в компе, или в мониторе ?  и тоесть это просто розетка, даже не кабель верно ? мне на комп надо, на экранах исправно все

Comment: Это разъём, здесь всё как у людей. Папа входит, мама на видяхе(и мониторе)(((

Comment: если не хочешь заморачиваться иди в отдел электроники и купи такой https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgJS9.png или такой как на рисунке https://i.stack.imgur.com/r912t.png смотри внимательней на картинку, не перепутай, потом втыкаешь его в видяху, ладно я ушёл.

Comment: по-моему второй не на мой случай https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf5Nr.png. а все, дошло. поэтому надо папа, а это мама. ок 

Comment: Тебе нужен такой: https://www.ozon.ru/product/dvi-hdmi-adapter-belsis-dvunapravlennyy-konverter-dvi-male-to-hdmi-female-podderzhka-1080p-265816986/ в отзывах много картинок со всех сторон. К нему присоеденяешь кабель HDMI и втыкаешь в моник. Или покупаешь провод DVI-D на HDMI как выше я скинул